# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head error when running docker build

Tags: docker

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY . .

# C-CPP
RUN apk update \
&& apk add build-base \
&& apk add g++

# JAVA 8
RUN apk fetch openjdk8 \
&& apk add openjdk8
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

# Python 3
RUN apk add python3 py3-pip \
&& apk add --upgrade bash

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./run.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./run.sh" ]
```

When I hit command `docker build -t dockerfile .`, I get this error - what does it mean and how to fix it?

```
> [+] Building 28.2s (3/3) FINISHED  => [internal] load build definition
> from Dockerfile                                    1.3s
> => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                 0.2s
  => [internal] load .dockerignore                   1.6s
  => => transferring context: 2B                     0.1s
  => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest      26.5s 
> ------
>  > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest:
> ------ 
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head
> "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest": di
```

al tcp 52.200.78.26:443: i/o timeout

Comment: can you check whether network connectivity is fine? connection getting timeout.

Comment: I think no problem with connect. Only 3 step have this erroe

Comment: I didn't get you, are you referring first 3 step have error? As per above , there is i/o timeout , is this error repeating?

Comment: I update question with add compile what say about error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly network timeout issue. There is no syntax error, shared dockerfile works fine.

How to verify network issue:
if you have curl tool

```
curl -v https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest
```

Output from  curl

[image]

or just type in browswer

`https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/alpine/manifests/latest`

Comment: What should the end of this curl output look like?  I have a line about authentication error.  I've done docker login, so it's a mystery...

Comment: Above curl command is to check the connectivity /timeout issue.  Yes it will give you authentication error , because curl is directly accessing the url, curl is not using your docker login token.   Authentication issue doesn't mean a timeout issue.        
 docker command is magical command which do lot of action under the single command. no comparison between 'curl and 'docker' command.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by stopping `buildx`: `docker buildx stop`

Comment: To avoid that buildx starts the container again and causing the same timeout issue, both `docker buildx stop` and `docker buildx rm` might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working by pulling the base image first:

```
docker pull alpine:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

i encounter this problem when i build image at offline enviroment.

disable buildkit then it fixed.

```
 export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
```