# Docker: ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

On Windows 10, Docker Desktop (Docker Engine v20.10.17, WSL enabled and running properly) fails to `docker build` an image (that, btw, works properly on Debian 11) throwing following error:

```
docker build -t <image-name> .
[+] Building 2.3s (3/3) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/rocker/r-base:4.2.1                2.0s
------                                                                                                                                                                     > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/rocker/r-base:4.2.1:                                                                                                            ------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get
"https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Arocker%2Fr-base%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io":
dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io: no such host
```

A [similar case was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194704/why-docker-build-failed), although the solution doesn't apply in my case. Searching the web yielded several similar (but not identical) cases with different solutions (including a reinstall), which all failed to solve this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the end I found a (or the) [solution in the Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/strange-docker-output-or-help-me-please-im-very-noob/100788/2):
in Docker Desktop, navigate to Settings > Docker Engine, change [`buildkit`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) to `false` in the Docker daemon configuration file and then click "Apply & Restart".

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar error: ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest

Comment: Works but loses all the buildkit avantages.

Comment: NOTE: daemon config file at ``C:\Users\<USER>\.docker\daemon.json``

Answer (score 4):

i encounter this problem when i build image at offline enviroment.

disable buildkit then it fixed.

```
 export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
```

Comment: Hey, your answer seems to be more a comment. You might want to adjust accordingly...

Comment: @bathyscapher Thank you for the reminder. I have already added the code.

Comment: Works for me though

Answer (score 2):

Solution 
sudo rm  ~/.docker/config.json 
Rerun restart

Comment: this gets the job done, things go back to normal with docker compose working again.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, the solution above didn't work for me but the following did:

```
docker pull <image-name>
```

Answer (score -1):

`docker pull [image-name]`
`docker build [...]`

On windows, I pulled the image first, then ran the build.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34626588)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).